# OpenLayers map in jquery UI dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, zooming, jquery-ui-dialog, openlayers

When I put OpenLayers map in a dialog, the zoom wheel seems not working. Also, when trying to resize the dialog, it is not that smooth. How to solve the two problems?

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ja7v2/2/

```
var div = $('<div />')
            .attr('id', 'map')
            .css({width:800,height:600})
            .appendTo($('body'));

//start a simple map, code from on http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/osm.html
map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map');

layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "Simple OSM Map");
map.addLayer(layer);
map.setCenter(
    new OpenLayers.LonLat(-71.147, 42.472).transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        map.getProjectionObject()
        ), 12
    );
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({
        zoomWheelEnabled: true,
    }));
// initialize the jQueryUI Dialog
div.dialog({
    width:800,
    height:600,
    title: 'My Map',
    resizeStop: function(){
        map.updateSize(); //to prevent drag-zoom error
    },
    dragStop: function(){
        map.updateSize(); //to prevent drag-zoom error
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

seems the jQuery dialog disables scrolling by default.

Adding this line solves the (your) problem:

```
$('#map').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

It's not the final solution, I believe, but shows you the way... :)

Comment: Yeah that works! Could you please explain a bit why the css works? Also, do you have some idea what the resizing problem?

Comment: Why it works, is just my quess, I don't know it for sure, but what I think is:
It works just because the jQuery handles the scrollbars inside the dialog. I think that it handles the scrolling, when overflow is set to "scroll", which is, I guess, the default value. Just because it isn't natural for the div to act as a separate window, i think there is this handler to override mousewheel functionality for the jQuery dialog to suppert the scrollbars functionality. And here we come with the outcome, that it doesn't work for the map, because it is overriden or whatever :) I guess :)

Comment: And why the resizing is so bad-working, I think it is just because the javascript and DIV elements aren't suitable for resizing. I've tried to solve this issue, but with no relevent outcome :( sorry for not helping on this issue :(
I advice you to set it to non-resizable and to use rather auto-resize or smthng...